# How to create a boxplot with customized quantiles in R?

Tags: r, boxplot, quantile

I am now dealing with some data and I want to make a boxplot showing minimum, 2.5, 25, 50, 70, 75, 97.5, and maximum. The boxplot should also have a legend showing lines with different colors to represent each quantile. Is there any way to do this? Thanks for any help.

```
set.seed(123)
Mydata = sample(x=100:300, size = 500, replace = T)
Mydata = c(Mydata, 1, 500)
boxplot(Mydata)
```

PS. I have tried the code provided by @thelatemail, but get a totally different figure in RStudio. Any solution to this? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Which quantiles should be shown in the "box" and which in the "whiskers"? Conventional boxplots only show 25 to 75 in the box and then there are slightly complicated rules for how the data outside of that is shown.

Comment: @Marius Hi, I am thinking to put 2.5, 25, 50, 70, 75, 97.5 in the "box" while minimum and maximum as "whiskers". Could you help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep overplotting using `bxp`:

```
set.seed(123)
Mydata = sample(x=100:300, size = 500, replace = T)
Mydata = c(Mydata, 1, 500)

bp <- boxplot(Mydata, range=0, plot=FALSE)

vals <- c(
  min=min(Mydata),
  quantile(Mydata, c(0.025, 0.25, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75, 0.975)),
  max=max(Mydata)
)

bxp(bp, whisklty=0, staplelty=0)
bp$stats[2:4,] <- c(vals[2], Inf, vals[5])
bxp(bp, whisklty=0, staplelty=0, add=TRUE)
bp$stats[2:4,] <- c(vals[2], Inf, vals[7])
bxp(bp, whisklty=1, staplelty=1, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. I have tried your code, but it produces a totally different figure with yours. Could you please check?

Comment: @YangYang - I just ran it and got the same result as shown. Did you close your existing boxplot window? This code needs to start from fresh.

Comment: Hi, I just notice that your code works in RGui, but not work in RStudio. Very strange...  Could you please try to make the code also work in RStudio? Thanks.

Comment: @YangYang - run `dev.new()` first to open a graphics window then run the code above. RStudio clearly doesn't respect the `add=TRUE` part of the code and generates a totally new plot each time. That seems to be RStudio's bug.

Comment: Hi, I have added `dev.new()` before your code, but it still does not work in RStudio. Maybe we have to go with RGui?

Comment: @YangYang - try running it twice in a row and then it will work. RStudio's embedded plot window doesn't play nicely it appears. I will file a bug report.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. A small question about the code, in `bp$stats[2:4,] <- c(vals[2], Inf, vals[5])`, why do you use `Inf`? What if we use `bp$stats[2:4,] <- c(vals[2], vals[5], vals[7]` so we can shorten the code?

Comment: @YangYang - certainly, the code can probably be simplified a little - it was a bit of a rush job and it shows. The `min` and `max` aren't needed either. The `Inf` was just used to suppress the median being plotted again. I'm basically just picking new values to graph each time from the `vals` subset.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do cannot be generated easily using the boxplot framework.

Underlying boxplots in R is the `boxplot.stats()` function. Let's run it on your data:

```
boxplot.stats(Mydata)

$stats
[1]   1 152 204 253 300

$n
[1] 502

$conf
[1] 196.8776 211.1224

$out
[1] 500
```

You can see that `$stats` returns in order: lower whisker, 25% quantile, median, 75% quantile, upper whisker. Compare with `quantile`:

```
quantile(Mydata)

  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   1  152  204  253  500
```

If you use `geom_boxplot()` from `ggplot2`, it's possible to redefine the values used for the box. But you can only draw the same five values: they are called `ymin`, `lower`, `middle`, `upper` and `ymax`.

So for example if you wanted the 2.5% quantile as `lower` and the 97.5% quantile as `upper`, you could try:

```
data.frame(x = 1,
           y0 = min(Mydata),
           y025 = quantile(Mydata, 0.025),
           y50 = median(Mydata),
           y975 = quantile(Mydata, 0.975),
           y100 = max(Mydata)) %>%
  ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = y0, 
                   lower = y025, 
                   middle = y50, 
                   upper = y975, 
                   ymax = y100),
               stat = "identity")
```

[image]

However, you would want to make it clear (using labels perhaps) that this is not a "standard" boxplot.

Another `ggplot2` idea is to use `geom_jitter` to plot the data points, then add lines for the desired quantiles using `geom_hline`. Something like this:

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

Mydataq <- quantile(Mydata, probs = c(0.025, 0.25, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75, 0.975)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames("value") %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "quantile")

Mydataq %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = value, color = quantile)) + 
  geom_jitter(data = tibble(x = "Mydata", y = Mydata), 
              aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Is it possible to plot 2.5, 25, 50, 70, 75, 97.5 in the "box" while minimum and maximum as "whiskers", just like a boxplot with 6 straight lines?

Comment: Not using `geom_boxplot`. You might be able to build up the box yourself using some other graphics function.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea. You might have to refine it further.

```
#Data
P = c(2.5, 25, 50, 70, 75, 97.5)

#Quantiles
b = quantile(x = Mydata, probs = P/100)

#Custom funtion
dp = function(at, y1, y2, width, ...){
    polygon(x = c(at - width/2, at + width/2, at + width/2, at - width/2),
            y = c(y1, y1, y2, y2), ...)
}

#Parameters
at = 1
width = 0.2

graphics.off()

#Whiskers
plot(x = rep(at, length(Mydata)), y = Mydata, type = "l")
segments(x0 = at - width/2, x1 = at + width/2, y0 = min(Mydata), y1 = min(Mydata))
segments(x0 = at - width/2, x1 = at + width/2, y0 = max(Mydata), y1 = max(Mydata))

#Boxes
sapply(1:ceiling(length(b)/2), function(i) {
    dp(at = at, y1 = b[i], y2 = b[length(b) + 1 - i], width = width * i, col = i)
})
#OR
sapply(1:ceiling(length(b)/2), function(i) {
    segments(x0 = at, x1 = at, y0 = b[i], y1 = b[length(b) + 1 - i],
             lwd = 10 * i, col = i, lend = "butt")
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you use lines instead of polygons? It might be better...

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution: If you only want to change part of the boxplot, here 25%- and 75% quantiles to 0.125, 0.9 quantiles:

```
set.seed(12345)
x <- rnorm(1000)
bp <- boxplot(x, whisklty=0, staplelty=0, range=1.5, plot=FALSE)
bp$stats[c(2, 4), ] <- quantile(x = x, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))
bxp(bp, whisklty=1, staplelty=1, boxfill = "red")
# To add more from inner to outer, e.g.
bp$stats[c(2, 4), ] <- quantile(x = x, probs = c(0.125, 0.9))
bxp(bp, whisklty=1, staplelty=1, boxfill = "lightgray", add=TRUE)
```

Looks the same as the original, just the box changed.